# How to solve the security errors in Tokens? (ERC223 )

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have written smart contract for basic ICO using ERC223 token Standard.
When I verified the code in securify.ch(https://securify.chainsecurity.com/) it is showing some security errors. Here is the code where I am getting those errors

Code:

```js
function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) public {
   uint codeLength;
   assembly {
      codeLength := extcodesize(_to)
   }
   balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
   balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);       
   if(codeLength>0) {
      ERC223ReceivingContract receiver = ERC223ReceivingContract(_to);
      receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
   }
   emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
}
```

In the below line, I am getting the errors.

```
receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
```

Error : This contract allows an arbitrary user to execute untrusted code on behalf of the contract. This is because any user can submit an arbitrary address `_spender` and arbitrary data `_data` which are provided as argument to the method. The address spender determines the target of the call instruction, while `_data` determines the function called in the untrusted contract.

Comment: I have edited your question to properly format your code and question. Could you please add the error messages you are getting to complete your question?

Comment: That behavior is intended for ERC223 tokens. I don't think it's something to "fix." (Unless you choose not to implement ERC223.)